# Postgres most common value query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to figure out how to structure some queries, and I am a bit lost.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dv_customer(
   customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name VARCHAR(50),
   last_name VARCHAR(50),
   email VARCHAR(50),
   address_id INTEGER,
   active BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE dv_address(
    address_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    address VARCHAR(50),
    address2 VARCHAR(50),
    district VARCHAR(50),
    city_id INTEGER,
    postal_code VARCHAR(50),
    phone VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TYPE MPAA_RATING AS ENUM(
'G',
'PG',
'PG-13',
'R',
'NC-17'
);

CREATE TABLE dv_film(
    film_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    description TEXT,
    length SMALLINT,
    rating MPAA_RATING,
    release_year SMALLINT
);

CREATE TABLE cb_customers(
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (last_name, first_name)
);

CREATE TABLE cb_books(
    title VARCHAR(50),
    author_id INTEGER,
    edition SMALLINT,
    publisher VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (title, author_id, edition)
);

CREATE TABLE cb_authors(
    author_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE mg_customers(
    customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    address_id INTEGER,
    active BOOLEAN
);
```

I need to figure out the following Queries:

What are the first and last names of all customers who live in the district having the most customers?

So far:

```
SELECT x.first_name, x.last_name
    FROM dv_customer x, dv_address y    
    WHERE x.address_id = y.address_id 
    AND (SELECT count(district)
    FROM dv_address >= SELECT count(district) FROM dv_address
   );
```

What are the first and last names of the top 10 authors when ranked by the number of books each has written? I want author name and book count, in descending order of book count.

So far:

```
SELECT x.first_name, x.last_name, count(y.title)
    FROM cb_authors x, cb_books y
    GROUP BY first_name, last_name
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

I know these are a bit of a mess, but they are the only queries I can't seem to figure out. Any help would be appreciated. I am a Postgres noob and just trying to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the first and last names of the top 10 authors when ranked by the number of books each has written

This kind of query is typically done using a window function:

```
select first_name, last_name, num_books
from (
  SELECT x.first_name, x.last_name, 
         dense_rank() over (order by count(y.title) desc) as rnk, 
         count(*) as num_books
  FROM cb_authors x
    join cb_books y on x.author_id = y.author_id
  GROUP BY x.author_id
) t
where rnk <= 10
```

Your from clause `FROM cb_authors x, cb_books y` is missing a join condition and thus creates a cartesian join between the two tables. It is a good example on why the implicit joins in the `where` clause are a bad thing. If you get in the habit of using an explicit `JOIN` operator you will never accidentally miss a join condition.

The above also uses `x.author_id` which is sufficient for grouping as it is the primary key of the column and all other (non-grouped) columns in the select list are functionally dependent on it.

Comment: That gave me a lot of weird output. It lists all the authors, and in the opposite order I need them. Still working on it.

Comment: @SeanLaney. ah, sorry. I missed the `DESC` for the order by

Answer (score 0):

The query below will give you the district with the most customers

```
select district
from dv_address
group by district
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Then you can select all customers living in that district with a sub query

```
select c.* from dv_customer c
join dv_address a on c.address_id = a.address_id
where a.district = (
    select district
    from dv_address
    group by district
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
)
```

Similarly you can get the top 10 author_id's with this query

```
select author_id 
from cb_books
group by author_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 10
```

Similarly, with a dervied table

```
select a.*, t.cnt from cb_authors a
join (
    select author_id, count(*) cnt
    from cb_books
    group by author_id
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 10
) t on t.author_id = a.author_id
order by t.cnt desc
```

Comment: Thanks! The first worked great. The second, I am having some issues with. The first query works fine. It gives me the correct author_id numbers in descending order. However, when I do the second, larger query, I get the correct authors, but not in the proper descending order. Also, I need to include a column with the count that is being used to determine the order. Any further refinements?

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. I learned quite a bit from your explanations.